# Rails: How is `translate` exposed to ActionController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Can anyone explain how `I18n.translate` is exposed to the `ActionController` class and can be used as plain `translate` or `t`?  I would like to tweak the `translate` code but can't understand how it is exposed - for example calling `translate.source_location` throws an error indicating that there is no method `translate` in class `ActionController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views and controllers you have access to `t` helper. Everywhere else you should be using `I18n.t`.

Here is where [ActionController::Base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L205) `include`s [AbstractController::Translation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/translation.rb) with two methods:

- [`translate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/translation.rb#L11) with alias `t`
- [`localize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/translation.rb#L24) with alias `l`

Comment: So do controllers automatically inherit from the view?  Your implementation shows the ActionView class but nothing for ActionController.  I ask because this is a follow on to me discovering that the 'raise exception on missing translation' only works in views and not in controllers.  I understand how the `t` helper is available for Views, but not how it is made available to controllers.

Comment: @Papadeltasierra I've edited the answer with some sources you could find useful. If it helped with your issue, please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Andrey - thanks.  In case anyone else is heading in the same direction, I would suggest looking at the `i18n-tasks` gem.  I've now stopped trying to force the ActiveController to throw exceptions and have an 'I18n integration test' which uses `i18n-tasks` to spot both missing and unused translations.